# Trying for a software developer job with 9 years of gap after education

Tags: employment-gaps

I graduated in 2015 with a mechanical engineering degree and didn't apply for a job at any private company, rather started preparing for government jobs and got obsessed with it. Cracked some written exams but rank was not good enough to get interviews. Continued with this approach till 2020, no progress.

Started freelancing work on chegg. In 2021 started to learn code on my own, but soon after that developed serious eye condition (keratitis), due to which I had to stay away from PC for few months, also lost the chegg work.

In 2023 I got an unpaid internship opportunity at a small startup, did it for 3 months after which I was offered with a full-time job as a junior developer, but had to let go off this opportunity due to the eye condition which resurfaced.

After recovering I started again.

My question - Is it possible for me to get a decent job in this field with this much gap (and counting) or should I do something else.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Will it be harder than if you had a software engineering degree and no gap? Yes as well.

Comment: If you're only starting to *learn* how to code at 30, I'd think you're on a hiding to nothing nowadays, as far as becoming a professional developer is concerned. It's not just that you're starting so late, it's the fact that such a late start implies a lack of real drive or attraction to the topic.

Comment: @Steve please make that an answer. Disclaimer: I will downvote it for the gate keeping it implies, expecting people to have worked out their life by 21 is unfair.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, my view is not about expecting people to have their life worked out. It's simply that if you haven't at least learned a programming language by time you've left compulsory education, you almost certainly won't get the bug later. It's like expecting to embark on a career as a professional music producer at 30, but you've never really picked up an instrument yet and you're still tone-deaf. It's not realistic in my view.

Comment: @Steve that's just a lot of nonsense. People can and do pivot their lives all the time. Can be from doing manual labor into law, from mechanical engineering into software devleopment and yes, even whatever they were doing into musical production. Maybe you canont, but that is definitely not a universal thing.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, this isn't an argument against being able to do more than one thing. I don't believe someone in the West can manage to get to age 30 today, and avoid learning (or fail to learn) a single programming language, and then suddenly have the necessary addiction to developing those skills to a decent commercially employable level. Not impossible; just vanishingly unlikely. It's getting to 30 without, which is a key signal about the affinities of their intellectual attention, and intrinsic interest in the subject of programming.

Comment: @Steve, thank you for your comments, but can you suggest - what should I do now?

Comment: @Steve It just doesn't. At all. You don't know people storeis, and not everyone was given the priveledges you had. Or exposure to things they may want doing before. In short your life experiences do not apply to others.

Comment: @op: if you want to follow that career just go and follow that career. You managed internships before, go get another one, this time a paid one. In the meanwhile keep working on your skills in spare time, start a github project and showcase hard work. Or contribute to existing ones. If you cannot afford to do that, well, do waht you need to pay the bills, and work on it and keep applying on the side.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, there's nobody in the West currently age 30, who has been "privileged" to access a PC or a programming language. You can switch to VB in Excel - ubiquitous in schools and workplaces, and long-pirated for home use - and be using a commercial grade programming language and IDE.

Comment: @Steve "there's nobody in the West currently age 30, who has been "privileged" to access a PC" you are wrong.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, well let's wait for the OP to clarify whether he comes from some kind of deprived background or place that might explain why computer equipment was hitherto unavailable to him

Comment: They don't have to and I hope they won't because of your bullish and unsubtantiated statements.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul, I think I'm making some commonsense assumptions about the modern world, for someone who speaks good English, claims to have sat a university degree, and is expressing an interest in programming. I'm simply making sense of the question as it is.

Comment: @Steve These claims are ridiculous, I have a great coworker who worked in warehouses until around 32 and is now working full time in IT.  He had to work hard in order to save up enough money to get himself a formal education.  Also OP was interested in mechanical engineering, it is not a stretch to think that kind of mind is ALSO interested in programming.  People do not only have a single interest they stick with their entire lives.

Comment: @Kupo, just to clarify, is your co-worker a *software developer* who never learned a *programming language* until he was 32? I keep having to say, this isn't an argument against learning new skills in middle age. It's the fact that it takes so much time, effort, and self-motivation to learn development skills, that it becomes unlikely that you'll develop the intense interest for the first time so late in life, and even if you do, you'll have life responsibilities which sap your available time and effort, and you'll be competing for jobs with those like me who first learnt programming at age 10

Comment: @Steve, I am not thinking about the past or the odds, instead working each day harder to improve my skills. As I asked earlier what is your opinion about other options open for me?

Comment: @user17666483, it's very difficult to give advice, but I think it's best to find something where learning feels more like leisure than work. Following my varying fascinations and obsessions has done far more for my skills in life than "working harder".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible doesn't necessarily mean easy, of course.

You might want to consider going back for an advanced degree, which could serve as evidence that you haven't forgotten too much, let you come back up to speed in a more flexible environment, and give you opportunity/reason to pick up recent concepts.

While there is a lot of demand for programming skill, there is also a huge amount of competition, for exactly the same reasons you're looking toward it. You might actually want to consider going back into the field you have academic credentials in, or looking for jobs where being fluent in both "languages" is valuable.

If vision might be a recurring /ongoing problem, I would suggest that you investigate assistive technologies at some point. There are people working successfully with low vision or no vision.  A large employer may have an office which facilitates this by providing tools to try out and see what works for you; other resources may exist in your area.

Comment: Very nice answer, beyond what OP actually asked! Definitely good shout on the assistive technologies, many vision impaired have sucesfull careers in IT as it's one of the easier fields to get around those limitations in. Very very few things that truly need vision (depends on exact field of IT of course).

Comment: Thank you. The assistive tech part was nice. Also can you elaborate - what does being 'fluent in both languages' mean.

Comment: Try looking for jobs that might need both basic programming skills (or whatever level of skill you're certain you have) and MechE. Working with structural simulation software, for example, or helping engineering customers explain their requirements to programmers. Yes, that's a smaller pool of jobs, but if you're applying for one of those you have a possible competitive advantage over someone who only knows coding; you understand the customers better and can probably communicate with them better, while understanding the programmers well enough to put those requirements in their terms.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible for me to get a decent job in this field with this much gap

Yes. It's possible.

Comment: That is what was asked

Comment: Does not mean it is likely. Recession and other factors make hiring on that level - interesting.

Comment: I didn't vote on this either way, but this answer would be improved with more explanation and supporting evidence.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you get a dev job then its fine- go with it, while you don't get one try finding any other job. This'll help you pay your bills and you will get a sense of financial independence. And work on your skills after the job hours.

It's not like only software engineers make a lot of money. There are so many other fields to work.

Answer (score -1):

You state that you have a recurring eye condition that prevents you from working with a computer for several months each time. That right there will prevent a career working with computers.

Almost every modern work involves computers. At this point, I would strongly advise looking into some field that does not require computer work.

Edit: Other people have worked around eye problems with assisted technologies. That you used the eye condition to avoid computers is more telling.

Comment: Keratitis is generally curable, it _shouldn't_ be a long-term condition.

Comment: And it needs not prevent working with computers. See my answer

Comment: @keshlam I agree that it doesn't prevent working with computers, but the OP states that he had to stay away from computers while having it. Had the OP used assistive technology, he might have been able to continue with freelance work already.

Comment: That was my point. Not everyone thinks of that option or is willing to invest the time and effort to find good choices before they must.

Comment: I worked with a blind programmer.  He used screen reading software and a braile keyboard.  So an eye condition isn't a disqualifier, although it will make things substantially harder.  Of course the ADA will help protect him if he can get his first job.  His lack of qualifications would be far harder to overcome.

Answer (score -3):

I would say no - no chance. You would have to lowball and go in in a time where we approach the perfect storm: a global recession may be looming (and if you are lucky and in the right place it may go over you without impact) and we are being hit with AI, so a LOT of places got a LOT more efficient in the next months. Even with AI not firing anyone, downsizing will also hit developers in many areas quite soon - 6 to 12 months, latest, already started in some companies I am talking to. Not saying there are no jobs - but, your resume does not look good and puts you at the end of a LARGE pile that is likely also growing.

And then there is the eye condition. That is a black mark - is it over? Because unless you can reliably point out why it is not an obstacle, you may or may not be disabled by law - you definitely are a high risk hire.

My AI keeps telling me that it may or may not be finally treatable - if you got 2 infections and your immune system is good, no risk, but you need a diagnosis of the underlying condition. Because that may really turn you into a bad ticket... especially...

That may be different if you have anything special to offer besides coding (as in: domain knowledge that you acquired) but - without it... Pile & Bottom. And Risk.

Sorry to blow it. But I see a large shift coming in jobs, and IT is next.